# Integral representation of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, linear-pde

Let $f \in C^{0}([0, \infty))$ satisfy $f(0)=0$. Find an integral representation for the solution of the problem:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u_{t}-u_{x x}=0, & \text { in }(0, \infty) \times(0, \infty) \\
u(x, 0)=f(x), & \text { for } x \in[0, \infty) \\
u(0, t)=0, & \text { for } t \in[0, \infty)
\end{array}\right.
$$

I have no idea how to start. I know the representation integrals for the homogeneous problem (containing the heat kernel) and Duhamel's principle for the non-homogenous problem. But is there any connection to inifinte propagation speed? if $f$ starts from zero doesn't it say that $u$ is identically zero?
would be grateful for a clue.

Comment: Note that $f$ is being specified as being zero at a single point, not the whole line (which would indeed result in an identically zero $u$). $f(0) = 0$ is just ensuring the initial condition satisfies the boundary condition $u(0,t) = 0$.

Comment: I used an odd extension of the initial data, so that the problem will be solved on the whole line, and then I took restriction to the half-line, to get the representation integral: $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}}f(y)-e^{-\frac{-(x+y)^2}{4t}}f(y)dy$$ Does it means that only in the origin of the space variable (in the initial data) the solution is zero?

Comment: This seems fruitful @matmat. Your $u$ satisfies $u(0, t) = 0$ for $t > 0$. Now use the standard analysis of this kernel to show it has the correct behavior as $t \rightarrow 0^+$.